# redirect to blog

Tags: .htaccess

Feel it a complicated rule, currently, I manage to point my folder to a new domain name.
domainA.com/folder/folder -> domainB.com

.htaccess code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} wildfiremedia.com.sg
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.wildfiremedia.com.sg$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.wildfiremedia.com.sg [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} wildfiremedia.com.sg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !w/w2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ w/w2/$1 [L]
```

However, I have a blog locate in the same location domainA.com/folder/folder,
how do I get domainB.com/blog to point to domainA.com/folder/folder/blog?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP for header redirection on your domainA.com/folder/folder/blog

Example
Create a index.php files in domainB.com
And put this code.

```
<?php
header("location: http://domainA.com/folder/folder/blog");
?>
```

For small redirection, you can use PHP code. But for big domain management, you should use .htaccess.